# SAPUI5 bindAggregation from XML Model by Attribute Name

Tags: javascript, xml, binding, model, sapui5

I do have a XML-Model which looks like this:
[image]

I would like to add the *sap.m.ComboBox* control to my UI. I want the value from attribute *Name* from the *Member* tag. I am able to do so with this code:

```
new sap.m.ComboBox({
    items : {
        templateShareable : true,
        path : "metadata>/edmx:DataServices/edm:Schema/edm:EnumType/0/edm:Member",
        template : new sap.ui.core.ListItem({
            text: "{metadata>@Name}"
        })
    }
})
```

BUT, instead of selecting the EnumType *hard* by calling it's index (*edm:EnumType/**0**/*), I would rather like to select it by it's attribute *Name*. E.g. something like this would be nice:

```
"metadata>/edmx:DataServices/edm:Schema/edm:EnumType(Name=RoleCategory)/edm:Member"
```

Does anyone know how to do so? Any idea is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing in the path syntax. You can see in the [OpenUI5 code](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/rel-1.38/src/sap.ui.core/src/sap/ui/model/xml/XMLModel.js#L295) that the path supports only

- attributes `@`
- `text()`
- elements by tag name
- array indices.

You cannot use element binding to filter either as element binding does not support filtering and sorting.

You could however attach to the models `requestCompleted` or `metadataLoaded` events and update the binding path or copy the data to a separate model.

If you want it dirty you could use a container control, bind it to /edmx:DataServices/edm:Schema/edm:EnumType with your `ComboBox` as template and apply an appropiate filter. You then have to use a relative path in you Combobox. :)